# sapui5 custom responsive design layout

Tags: layout, responsive-design, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and I am having trouble creating a layout which should be responsive, I tried responsive layout, responsive grid layout but with no luck, also to mention below every label a textbox should be there.

[image]

Comment: please insert your image into the question. Thanks. There is a image symbol in the editor to do this.

Comment: tried but got an error,i need 10 reputation points to post images

Comment: To get more specific answers, please include what you did (source code if available) and what you see (error message or wrong layout) or a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the example pages from SAP?

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/layout/demokit/ResponsiveGridLayout.html

Klick on "show source" to see how they did it.